# TSQL Logic in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, report, logic

I am building a report which has the header field as `PropertyStatementForHalfyear Ending :<Date>`

So in the `DATE` field I need to put either `May 28` or `Nov 28` depending on the date the report Runs

Whats The logic I need to write ??

- For example if I run the report today i.e. June 22, I need to display  `PropertyStatementForHalfyear Ending : 28 Nov 2013`
- if I run it in December 2013, I need to display `PropertyStatementForHalfyear Ending : 28 May 2014`

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
DECLARE @DateThreshold1 DATE = '20130528'
DECLARE @DateThreshold2 DATE = '20131128'

DECLARE @CurrentDate DATE = '20131201'

IF @CurrentDate > @DateThreshold2
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), DATEADD(YEAR, 1, @DateThreshold1), 106)
ELSE IF @CurrentDate > @DateThreshold1
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @DateThreshold2, 106)
ELSE
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @DateThreshold1, 106)
```

- For dates from `20130101` through `20130528`, this will return `28 May 2013`
- For dates from `20130529` through `20131128`, this will return `28 Nov 2013`
- For dates past `20131128`, this will return `28 May 2014`

You can easily package this up into a function or a SSRS code snippet

Comment: Thanks much ! but at the same time can u also give me the code so that it can run for any given year . not just for 2013 and 2014 . for example if i run the report on dec 1 2019 it should give me the result as Prop statement for financial year ending May 28 2020

Comment: @OneThinker: yes, it might need a little bit of your own effort to make it work entirely - I tried to show you as a general template how to do it for a given year. It is left to the reader (e.g. you) to extend this so it can handle *any* year ....

Answer (score 1):

If you're not into IF/CASE statements, like me:

```
with dt as 
(select CAST('2013-11-28' as datetime) dt) --dt becomes your datetime column.
, ymdt as (select 
    DATEPART(year, dt) y,
    DATEPART(month, dt) m,
    DATEPART(day, dt) d,
    dt
    from dt) --split into year, month and date for readability
select y, m, d, dt,
    DATEADD(month, 5 + d/28 - (m + d/28) % 6, --add months depending on month and day
    DATEADD(day, 28 - d --go to the correct day
    , dt) --start calculation from dt (the sql date functions' parameter order has always baffled me)
    ) HalfYearEndDate 
from ymdt
```

The SQL engine merges all of this into one big fat constant scan or scalar expression on your datetime column.

You should create a SQL or VB function for this if you need this in other reports and also so it doesn't clutter up your queries.

Also: Don't do text formatting in T-SQL unless absolutely necessary! Return a datetime column and do it in the report itself. The format you need to set on the textbox is "dd MMM yyyy" (without the quotes when using the designer).